# Return count for each distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
ORDER

OrderId
-------
Order1
Order2
Order3

CUSTOMERORDER

OrderId  CustomerId
-------  ----------
Order1   Cust1
Order1   Cust2
Order2   Cust3
Order3   Cust1
```

The query

```
select distinct count(*) as CustomersPerOrder
from CustomerOrder
group by CustomerOrder.OrderId
order by CustomersPerOrder
```

returns

```
CustomersPerOrder
-----------------
1
2
```

That is, some orders have 1 customer, some have 2. I also want to know how many orders have 1 customer, and how many have 2:

```
CustomersPerOrder  OrdersCount
-----------------  -----------
1                  2
2                  1
```

That is, 2 orders (OrdersCount) have 1 customer (CustomersPerOrder), and 1 order (OrdersCount) has 2 customers (CustomersPerOrder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CustomersPerOrder, COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(*) as CustomersPerOrder
from CustomerOrder
group by CustomerOrder.OrderId
) sub
GROUP BY CustomersPerOrder
```

Comment: Some may argue against subquery, but cost not different from DISTINCT.

Comment: Thanks, I have been struggling with this for some time! Not worried about the cost.

Answer (score 2):

put away the distinct and count the occurences of and group the CustomersPerOrder

```
with counter as (
 select count(customerid) as CustomersPerOrder
 from CustomerOrder
 group by CustomerOrder.OrderId
)
select CustomersPerOrder, COUNT(*) as OrdersCount 
from counter
group by CustomersPerOrder
```